# VS Code keyboard shortcut stopped working (seems to wait for further strokes)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following keyboard shortcut configured: <kbd>CMD+L</kbd> for **Expand Line Selection**:

[image]

This used to work without problem but seemingly from one moment to another it stopped working.

For example, when I am in an `index.html` file and I would expect to be able to select a line with that shortcut, nothing happens *in the editor*. However, in the VS Code [Status Bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface), the message appears:

```
(⌘L was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...)
```

Here's a screenshot of this:

[image]

It seems like instead of immediately "executing" the <kbd>CMD+L</kbd> shortcut, VS Code waits for another shortcut to come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure have seen this before, sound like an extension causing it! Maybe search for “@installed” in extensions and try to find the culprit!

From VSCode CLI, you can run the following command to list all extension

```
code --list-extensions
```

From VSCode GUI, you can go to the extensions tab and search for

```
@installed
```

[Picture of VSCode Extensions Tab with `@Installed` in the Search Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBCxg.png)